# How to replace numbers with a string that are surrounded by double quotes in python?

Tags: python, flask

I have a JSON string that looks like this

```
[{"25":"Fresh Vegetable Platter with Olive Oil Dip "},{"23":"Ginger-Lime Coconut Cake with Marshmallow Frosting "},{"26":"Mexican Pineapple Salad "},{"28":"Saut\u00e9ed Savoy Cabbage with Scallions and Garlic "},{"24":"Braised Escarole with Currants and Pine Nuts "}]
```

I want to replace the numbers with the word title but where the numbers in the "Saut\u00e9ed" part are causing a problem because I want to keep that that way.

I have tried:

```
recommendations = re.sub('\d', 'title', recommendations)
```

this gives me this:

```
[{"titletitle":"Fresh Vegetable Platter with Olive Oil Dip "},{"titletitle":"Ginger-Lime Coconut Cake with Marshmallow Frosting "},{"titletitle":"Mexican Pineapple Salad "},{"titletitle":"Saut\utitletitleetitleed Savoy Cabbage with Scallions and Garlic "},{"titletitle":"Braised Escarole with Currants and Pine Nuts "}]
```

Comment: `\d` matches a single digit.  So of course `25` becomes `titletitle`.

Comment: `\d+` will match with multiple character

Answer (score 1):

If you replace:

```py
recommendations = re.sub('\d', 'title', recommendations)
```

with

```py
recommendations = re.sub('\d+', 'title', recommendations)
```

it should work.

The `+` tells the regex to match 'at least one (but possibly more) digits'.

For future reference in regex you can use these characters to indicate a specific number of occurrences to match:

- `?` 0 or 1 occurrences
- `+` 1 or more occurrences
- `*` any number of occurrences (includes zero)

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
recommendations = re.sub(r'\d+','title', recommendations )
```

Answer (score 0):

Given you want "Saut\u00e9ed" not to be affected, here's a list comprehension for fun:

```
a = [{"25":"Fresh Vegetable Platter with Olive Oil Dip "},{"23":"Ginger-Lime Coconut Cake with Marshmallow Frosting "},{"26":"Mexican Pineapple Salad "},{"28":"Saut\u00e9ed Savoy Cabbage with Scallions and Garlic "},{"24":"Braised Escarole with Currants and Pine Nuts "}]

b = [{'title': list(i.values())[0]} for i in a]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recommendations =  re.sub(r'"\d+"', '"title"', recommendations)
```

this worked, this only replaces the numbers wrapped in ""